# What is the optimal way to cut B chocolate bars to share equally between N people, but all people receiveing congruent shape parts

Tags: optimization

What is the optimal way to cut B chocolate bars to share equally between N people, but all people receiving **congruent shape parts**?

Without the constraint of congruent shape parts, the question was solved [here in this group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252146/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-cut-b-chocolate-bars-to-share-equally-between-n-peopl).

I've found [this article](http://digitalcommons.utep.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1229&context=cs_techrep) that uses unitary fractions (Egyptian Fractions) to minimize the arithmetic mean of the number cuts to produce congruent shape parts. But I'm looking for a procedure to minimize the number of cuts, not their mean, while sharing congruent shape parts.

Thanks!

Comment: I seem a bit confused. Wouldn't minimizing the arithmetic mean simultaneously minimize the total number?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, by minimizing the arithmetic mean, the cited article admits that the number of pieces received by each people is not an integer number anymore, so it leaves the realm of integer programming and, doing so, it is not realistic.

Comment: I wonder why it is so hard to find any good references about a simple problem. :(

Comment: The problem is *simple* but not *easy*. Another example: If a *baguette* is randomly split into 3 pieces, what's the expected length of the largest piece ? The correct answer is far from would you'd *expect*.